# Dividing N 2D object to groups of K objects with minimum inner-group average distance

Tags: algorithm, optimization, computational-geometry

I have N two-dimensional objects.
I would like to divide them into groups of size K, with the minimum average distance between each objects of the group, as possible.

Can it be done without using any special libraries?
Run time can be flexible (knowing that N<150)

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: how is the average distance between objects defined given that each object consists is 2 dimensional?

Comment: Have you searched for the problem? What did you get?

Comment: @user1984 - It can be in any metric from my side, But I thought about minimal sum of all groups average, for example.

Comment: @Trilarion - Yes. I didn't find anything related but KNN, which is different.
And I didn't manage to convert some clustering algorithms to my needs.

Comment: Lookup "clustering algorithms". If I am right there is no fast algorithm for an exact solution.